# Deno permissions (--allow-net)

Tags: deno

The one day old [docs](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/permissions) is not clear enough for me to know..

How to give global permission to all websites (for debugging stuff) in my deno project like..

```
deno run --allow-net=* deno.ts
```

or something like that

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use `--allow-net` without anything else.

Unless you specify something, you will give permission to all network calls.

```sh
# All requests allowed
deno run --allow-net deno.ts

# only calls to stackoverflow.com
deno run --allow-net=stackoverflow.com deno.ts
```

The same goes for all the other permissions.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to allow urls from either one domain or multiple domains.

```
# For one domain permission: 
  deno run --allow-net=xyz.com

# For multiple domains, give comma separated values: 
  deno run --allow-net=xyz.com,abc.com
```

adding xyz.com/api/v1/user/ and protocols like http, are not needed.